# Reset ONLY ONE specific filtering scheme in Spotfire by using a Python script

Tags: python, filtering, reset, spotfire

I would like to have a Python script that allows me to reset only one specific filtering scheme in Spotfire. This filtering scheme does not necessarily need to be the active filtering scheme on the page.

The name of an example filtering scheme in my Spotfire file is "Customer_settings"

I only managed to obtain a script from the web that is resetting ALL schemes (see below) and additional I would like to have a script in which I can specify only single filtering scheme to be reset.

Script for resetting ALL schemes:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

def resetAllFilteringSchemes():

     # Loop through all filtering schemes

     for filteringScheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:

          # Loop through all data tables

          for dataTable in Document.Data.Tables:

               # Reset all filters

               filteringScheme[dataTable].ResetAllFilters()                        

# Call the function

resetAllFilteringSchemes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

for filteringScheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:
   if(filteringScheme.FilteringSelectionReference.Name == 'Customer_settings'):
      for DataTable in Document.Data.Tables:
         filteringScheme[dataTable].ResetAllFilters()
```